# Websocket having Error: Frame must be terminated with a null octet while using Cyrillic instead of english

Tags: c#, websocket, encoding, cyrillic

I am having a problem with sending a cyrillic (russian letters) instead of english ones to server(java spring boot utf-8). Here are my frames examples below. The one with english works fine, but cyrillic have a wrong calculating null octet. I am using websocket-csharp-net-stomp-client for it.
I have also tried to change encoding of the string with message to UTF-8

The one that works:

[image]

The one that does not work:

[image]

```
public static string SendMessage(string messageText, string chatID)
    {

        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16"); //also tried encode by 1251 instead of utf-16
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(messageText);
        byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, utf16, utf8Bytes);
        string msg = utf16.GetString(isoBytes);
        
        StompMessageSerializer serializer = new StompMessageSerializer();

        var content = new MessageContent() { text = msg };
        var broad = new StompMessage("SEND", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content));
        broad["token"] = $"{Global.AuthCompTokenFinal}";
        broad["contentType"] = "application/json"; 
        broad["destination"] = $"/app/send/{chatID}";

        var str = serializer.Serialize(broad);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Global.ws.Send(str);
        return str;
    }
```

content length is getting here (library text)

```
internal StompMessage(string command, string body, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        stompCommand = command;
        Body = body;
        nativeHeaders = headers;

        this["content-length"] = body.Length.ToString();
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Here is an error example:
[image: Here is an error example]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65868838/edit) your question for adding additional information instead of posting comment.

Comment: You may need to use encoding Window 1251 which uses cyrillic characters using 8 bits instead of 16 bits.   Since you are using UTF-8 you must encode using Window 1251

Comment: @jdweng did u mean , that i should try to sand text encoded by win1251?

Comment: Use following and make sure you view results in a viewer that support the font :            Encoding encod1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
            string msg = encod1251.GetString(isoBytes);

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted `this["content-length"] = body.Length.ToString();` and encoding to UTF-8
and it works fine . Wow